# RemoveHandler for nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver, debian

in my website users can upload their files and have a short url of that files.
before this i used apache webserver but now i want to switch to nginx.

in apache i used this snippet to remove php handler for some directory that files are upload to that :

```
<Directory /var/www/unkown-user-data/uploads>
RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3 .php5
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3 .php5
php_flag engine off
AddHandler default-handler .php
</Directory>
```

but now, how should am i do this on nginx webserver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx doesn't have a removehandler directive. You add location blocks to server different types of requests.

I assume that the uploads folder could have .php .phtml .php3 .php5 files that you don't want to execute them when it's requested from that folder. Here is my suggestion:

```
location ^~ /uploads/ {
  root /var/www/unkown-user-data;
  expires max;
}
```

Note: "^~" is important (It means to have higher priority than regex "~" blocks). Otherwise a regex location blocks such as

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  ...
}
```

will be matched first and the php script will be mistakenly executed. Here is the match order in nginx wiki:

> ```
> 1. Directives with the "=" prefix that match the query exactly (literal string). If found, searching stops.
> 2. All remaining directives with conventional strings. If this match used the "^~" prefix, searching stops.
> 3. Regular expressions, in the order they are defined in the configuration file.
> 4. If #3 yielded a match, that result is used. Otherwise, the match from #2 is used.
> ```